# How to run mobile app on chrome os?

Tags: google-chrome-os

As a portable app doesn't need installation like a program but only exe to click on, I wonder if it is possible to run a portable application on chrome os?

Answer (score 4):

No. Chrome OS doesn't support any Windows based executables - portable or otherwise

Comment: Sathya's answer is correct. You should upvote and select as best answer if you concur